# (how) can I make a whole package private in scala

Tags: scala, package, private

I would like to make all content of a package private to be usable only inside its library, without having to add `private[...]` to all classes and objects.
So I tried to make the package object private:

```
package org.whatever

private[whatever] package object internalstuff
```

But the compiler didn't like that (expected start of definition...).

How could I do that?

Comment: I don't think you should make that a package when it's part of the library package.

Comment: Well, the package is quite huge, but I'd like to clearly state what is its public API, and thus what is not. how should I do that?

Comment: make it a regular (not package) private object, and move the stuff you want hidden inside of it.

Comment: @Dima I guess this is an answer, so you should post it. Not satisfying for me because the packages I want hidden are big (>10s of files). But it is the only solution so far :-\